Why do all materials appear grey and foggy in the renderview and shading tab?
I installed blender yesterday and tried modeling a cloud. But for some reason, it appears grey and I couldn't change its color in Cycle. So I added a default cube and another cube with a golden material in the scene to compare their rendering. 
The material looked as intended in the material preview but looked grey and foggy in the render. I checked if the material was applied (it was), if I was in the good viewport shading (It was as well), if the object was properly illuminated (see spot preferences).
Then I tried switching the processing method from GPU to CPU (it doesn't change anything) and switching the render engine from Cycles to Eevee but the foggy render rest.
I use the version 4.1 of blender on linux. Do you have any ideas on what I am doing wrong? There is my blender file: https://wetransfer.com/downloads/4b6338b73eb5cb12a8458ba4972aad0120240426121737/b809c5feea3016c6a7d14f50c5681b6720240426121927/cbaa54

Your central big cube has 2 materials. Remove the first one Material.001 and that's it.

Thank you! It solved the problem!

@kliv91 Just for clarification: of course you can have more than one material on an object, but by default the first material slot and whatever material is set there will be assigned to all faces. Adding a second slot and material will not replace it. To switch to the second material (apart from deleting the first) you could go into Edit Mode and select some or all faces and with the new material selected hit the Assign button underneath to give this material to the selected. This way you can assign different materials to different faces of the same object.

If you want to know more about how the assigning of material slots and materials works read my answer to this question: Something strange with material slots
